# Common web servers/frameworks for deploying python machine learning models?

Tags: python, webserver, tornado, gunicorn, web-frameworks

I noticed both [Databricks MLFlow](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/61) and [Amazon Sagemaker](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container) both make use of the combination of Nginx, Gunicorn, and Flask.

I was wondering if that tends to be the standard stack for deploying machine learning models (e.g. Scikit-learn, Tensorflow, Keras).

If so, is there are reason those are used over alternatives like Tornado?

If not, is there a "standard stack"

Comment: This migth help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766684/what-benefit-is-added-by-using-gunicorn-nginx-flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, main reason for choosing a Flask over Tornado as a web-framework to wrap ML is that Flask's is simple but feature-rich (using addons). ML in general is CPU and RAM bound and the main advantage of the Tornado is effective handling of IO-bound operations, which is not the case for ML. But choosing Tornado for ML means more complex development for litte-to-zero benefit. It would be wiser if you have main app in Tornado (if you really need to) and use ML with Flask as a microservice to your main app.